# Generic icons in Finder side bar?

Tags: finder, macos, icon, sidebar

I am running into an issue whereby the icons for things like 'Music', 'Movies' and 'Pictures' in the windows of the Finder side bar are showing up as generic document icons. I should note, that device icons are displaying correctly.

Also, if I relaunch the Finder then the icons disappear and I need put them back, via the Finder preferences.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

I am using macOS X Sierra (10.12).

Below is screenshot illustrating what I am seeing:

[image: Screen shot showing issue]

Answer (score 1):

Removing the files in ~/Library/Preferences, containing 'finder' in their name seems to have resolved the issue.